# Bash scripting - nested variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

I currently encountered a tricky problem on which I couldn't find any solution yet.

I wrote a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh 
x=1
while [ "$x" -le $# ]; do
echo "$x"'. Argument is: ' "\$$x"
x="$(( $x + 1 ))"
done
```

I suggested that the shell would evaluate the expression "\$$x" after expanding the variables to get access to the argument on position x but the output is:

```
1. Argument is: $1
```

Please help. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fix

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

x=1
while [ "$x" -le $# ]; do
echo "$x"'. Argument is: ' "${!x}"    # If you need indirect expansion, use ${!var} is easier way.
x="$(( $x + 1 ))"
done
```

Test result

```
$ sh a.sh a b c
1. Argument is:  a
2. Argument is:  b
3. Argument is:  c
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The fix works on bash but I still got a problem since I'm writing the script on my DD-Wrt router which comes with busybox v1.22.0 and an 'ash' implementation that puts out the following: 

`syntax error: bad substitution`

Comment: Won;t work in bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
x=0
args=($@)
while [ "$x" -lt $# ]; do
    echo "$x"'. Argument is: ' "${args[${x}]}"
    x="$(( $x + 1 ))"
done
```